# Can I use Logger.log(Object format, Object...values):Logger in place of Logger.log(message)?

Tags: google-apps-script

I used Logger.log(message) quite heavily when debugging Google Apps Scripts, particularly when calling functions from Libraries where using the debugger is not (yet) supported.

I noticed a new option appearing in recent days: 
Logger.log(Object format, Object...values):Logger

I ignored it to start with but within the past few hours Logger.log(message) has disappeared from the options when you type your script so now I'm stuck.

There's no documentation on Logger.log(Object format, Object...values):Logger yet. Can it be used instead of Logger.log(message)?

I've added a comment about this to [Issue 1681](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1681&q=Logger&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) because it seemed relevant.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use Logger.log(message) as they have it retained for backward compatibility. And keep watching the release notes to hear more about the new options.